# How to remove Quill.js toolbar border?

Tags: javascript, css, quill

Im using quilljs and would like to remove the border around the toolbar, i don't know how to select the right element but i have tried:

```
.ql-toolbar
   border: none
   shadow: none
   outline: none
```

Comment: You can use css by set `.ql-toolbar.ql-snow { border: none !important;}`

Comment: Thank you so much!! Answer the question so i can mark it as solution <3

Comment: You're welcome. There is no need to do this. GoodLuck :)

Comment: how to do it conditional?

Answer (score 3):

For people coming with similar questions about quilljs borders, you could remove it by looking at the element via `devtools -F12` and `setting border to zero` . *Similarly you can remove other borders and manipulate other properties, not just the border*

for  example to remove borders of full editor

```
.ql-container.ql-snow{ border: none !important;}
```

why? because thats the element popping out in the dom
[image: Inspecting element]

Also I was inspired from comments answer which was given by
**Farid Vatani** for removing toolbar borders

```
ql-toolbar.ql-snow { border: none !important;}
```